# Java-Optional versus C++-optional

Tags: java, c++, java-stream, monads, option-type

Am I right in assuming that the Java-`Optional` does not have much todo with the C++17-`optional`?

I know Javas `Optional` mostly from use in the Stream-API, e.g.:

```
Optional<Integer> op  = Optional.empty(); 
op.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

I know it has its uses as a return value as well (not so much as parameter). But concerning this kind of use this is not applicaple to the C++-`optional`, right?

Or is it "[Monads](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0798r0.html)" again, the thing no-one can explain after understanding it? Does the C++-`optional` have in fact everything to do with Monads, and so have Java-Streams, and thus C++-`-optional` is comparable to Java-`Optional`? What would be an comparable example, then?

Comment: C++ is not Java. Don't assume that *anything* you know about one language carries over to the other.

Comment: On the off chance you are porting code, I suggest a different path: Port the behaviour. Understand the behaviuor described by the Java code and reimplement the behaviour in C++ 1:1 translations of code tend to wind up with sub optimal results, assuming that the result does anything useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

Optionals in Java and in C++ (and in a lot of other programming languages) serve a similar purpose - to represent a value that may be present or absent.

Optionals in Java are not only used for streams, they can (and should) be used in their own right. That being said, in Java optionals should be used only as return types of methods that may or may not return a value. The same can be achieved with returning `null` values, but with that it's much easier to forget to check the returned value. But optionals in Java aren't supposed to just replace every object that may not actually be present (like `Maybe` in Haskell, for example).

I'm not an expert in C++, but it looks like C++'s `optional` has largely the same purpose (correct me if I'm wrong).

I won't explain what monads are here, but the concept is quite easy and I really don't know why so many people are afraid of them. If you've read anything about monads, you know that they basically have 2 operations: create a monadic value, and bind it (or flat-map it).

In Java, `Optional.of` creates an optional value, and `Optional.flatMap`, well, flat-maps it. But these operations don't fully respect the monadic laws, so purists claim that optionals in Java are not *really* monads.

In C++, you can create an optional using the constructor or the `make_optional` function, so you have the operation of creation. But I can't find the `bind` or `flat_map` function in the standard library. If you wish, you can write one yourself - then if that function respects the monadic laws, the optional will become a monad.

Comment: flatMap+bind missing, no monad. ok and thanks.. Haskells `Maybe` is needed because of no `null`. "Purists claim `Optional` not *really* monads"? Really? If it is debatable if a something as simple as a tuple/triple of lambdas is a monad or not, how can monads then "not be something to be afraid of" ;-)

Comment: @towi The concept of monads is not difficult in itself. But if you get down to technical details, such as monad laws and the underlying math, it may get really difficult really fast. However, most people don't need to know about the underlying concepts to use monads and to understand their concept on a higher level.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in assuming that the Java-Optional does not have much todo with the C++17-optional?

They are similar in that they kind of model the same concept - a value that can be absent, but their interfaces are very different. I am not very knowledgable about C++, but looking at [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), I can see that C++'s `std::optional` is a lot less *functional* than Java's `Optional`.

> Or is it "Monads" again, the thing no-one can explain after understanding it?

Spot on! Java's `Optional` is essentially a monad. By having `Optional.of`, and `Optional.flatMap` methods, the Java `Optional` becomes a monad. The C++ optional lacks a corresponding `flatMap` method, which causes it to not be a monad :(

IMO, `std::optional` not having a `flatMap` method is the fundamental between the two types in question. `flatMap` has the signature:

```
<U> Optional<U> flatMap(Function<? super T, Optional<U>> mapper)
```

Essentially allowing you to *compose* `Optional`s. You can have a `Optional<String>`, apply a function that returns another `Optional<T>` to it, and then get back an `Optional<T>`.

Here is a [paper](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) about Monads that might help. Monads aren't really that scary. The key feature is a function with the same signature as `flatMap` shown above. If you see something like that, there's a good chance you've found a monad! `Stream` is therefore a monad.

Comment: "Monads aren't really that scary"... haha, yeah, and I even used them. And without knowing that they are monads. https://bartoszmilewski.com/2011/07/11/monads-in-c/, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/WadlerMonads.pdf.